# GET request with header attribute set to None raises TypeError with urllib3

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

How do you pass `None` as the value of a parameter in a GET request header with urllib3 without raising a TypeError?

I have tried using `requests` and it works there, but the package lacks some features of `urllib3` regarding proxy management, pooling, and simplicity, which sadly are necessities for this project.

My code currently looks like this:

```
headers = {}
headers.setdefault("Attribute", None)

r = urllib3.PoolManager().request("GET", url="someurl.xyz", headers=headers)
```

This raises a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, because None seems to be an illegal header value.

Here's the relevant part of the log:

```
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Project/src/main/classes/oof.py", line 54, in set_fingerprint
    r = self.session.request('GET', url=experiment_url, headers=headers)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 324, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1270, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1206, in putheader
    if _is_illegal_header_value(values[i]):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Is there a way to circumvent this error with `urllib3`?

Comment: Have you tried `headers.setdefault("Attribute", "")` (`""` instead of `None`)?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass empty string as an empty header, not None